# How I can read a paragraph from the keyboard and stored it in a linked list (each node has a one word)?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class node
{
private:
    string data;
    node *next;
public:
    node*head,*current,*tail;
    node()
    {
     head=current=tail=NULL;
    }
    void read()
    {
     string x;
     tail=new node;
     cin>>tail->data;
     tail->next=NULL;
     head=current=tail;
     cin>>x;
     while(x!=".")
     {
      current=new node;
      current->next=NULL;
      stringstream ss;//("plez help me");
      string s;
      //getline(cin,aa);
      while (getline(ss, s,' ')) 
        {
            cout << s << "\t";

        }
      current->data=s;
      tail->next=current;
      tail=tail->next;
      //cin>>x;
     }
    }
    void print()
    {
     current=head;
     while(current!=NULL)
     {
      cout<<current->data<<endl;
      current=current->next;
     }
    }
};
```

Comment: What's your question? There's just poorly formatted code here.

Comment: how I can read a paragraph and save it into linked list ??

Comment: If this is homework, please add the "homework" tag.

Comment: You've got some code up, great, but you've not said what is actually wrong with your code, we don't have the time nor necessarily the inclination to build a full example to test your code - you need to post full code and what is wrong vs. expected output - then may be we can highlight some areas for you to look at.

Comment: Youv'e been asked multiple times to show what the problem is, but you've failed to do this.  So -1 and vote to close until you get this clarified.  We're not your personal team of code monkeys.

Comment: so sorry guyz I'm Apologizes but I'm really need the answer for my question

Comment: @asem:  Then ask a better question.  What did you expect your code to do?  What does it actually do?  What specifically do you not understand?

Comment: i just wont to read a paragraph into linked list and my code above it's not accurate

Comment: What's not accurate about it? Is there a syntax error? Does it seg fault? Do you get a kernel panic?

Comment: Why would a node object handle its own input? Sound pretty incorrect to me.

Comment: there is no syntax error but there is no output just"press any key to continue"

Comment: @asem: and what happens after you press a key?

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is a homework assignment, don't make your own linked-list class, just use `std::list`.

std::cin will input one word at a time by default.  Just call it multiple times, and it will read the source one word at a time.

Edit: your `node` class is trying to do too many things.  Each node has a pointer for `next`, `head`, `current`, and `tail`.  You're mixing the concept of the whole list, and a single node  within that list.

You should have a function (maybe call it `addNode`) which makes a new node, and inserts it after the last node.  Then call `addNode` from `read`.

You don't need to use a stringstream.  cin will separate based on spaces.

`while(x!=".")` won't stop at the end of a sentence unless the `.` appears all by itself:

```
Sample input: this is a test.  // this won't satisfy the test
              this is a test . // this will
```

In the first example, the test will see "test.", and keep going.

Start simple: make a read function that works for a single word, first.

Comment: no it's a homework so I need to do it like that !

Comment: @asem: so, what is wrong with the code you posted?  What does it do, and what were you expecting it to do?

Comment: i was tried to solve the question but I failed can u help me plez

Comment: @asem: Complete the following sentence: "I tried to solve the question by doing ________, but instead ______ happened."

Comment: I have two problem the first one I'm not good in programing and

Comment: the second the died line for my assignment is tomorrow

Comment: if you know how I can read a paragraph and save it in a linked list pleez tell me

Comment: @asem: if you're not going to cooperate then you won't finish your assignment for tomorrow.

Comment: @asem: **Tell us what you tried, and why you think it didn't work.**  Don't tell us when this is due: we don't care.  Don't repeat the question: we know what it is.  Complete the following sentences: "I did _______, but it did not work.  I know it did not work, because ______ happened."

Comment: i would to cooperate what I can do ?

Comment: ok I tried to read a paragraph using getline and save it in a linked but that doesn't work

Comment: @asem: How do you know it didn't work?  What did it do instead?

Comment: there is no error but when I execute the program there is nothing appear in a console window just "press any key to continue"

Comment: @what does your `main` function look like?

Comment: @asem: the code you posted doesn't have a `main()` function, so nothing is being run.

Comment: in the main I create an object from the node class and call the read and print functions

Comment: {node call;call.read();call.print(); }

Comment: "no it's a homework so I need to do it like that !", "the [dead]line for my assignment is tomorrow". So which is it? Is it homework or not?

Comment: @asem: I've updated with some advice.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
list<string> result;
typedef istreambuf_iterator<char> InIter;
typedef boost::char_separator<char> CharSep;
boost::tokenizer<CharSep, InIter> tok(
    InIter(cin.rdbuf()), InIter(), CharSep(" \t\r\n."));
copy(tok.begin(), tok.end(), back_inserter(result));
```